# Aldec Active-HDL: vlib in GUI gives "Warning: Cannot create library" without usable library

Tags: vhdl, active-hdl

From the Aldec Active-HDL GUI the `vlib` should create a work library, e.g.:

```
vlib my_lib
```

This creates a "my_lib" directory under the current directory, but with the warning:

> Warning: Cannot create library

A subsequent `set worklib my_lib` fails with error "Error: Design not loaded.", and a compile with `vcom -work my_lib tb.vhd` completes without output and neither compiles anything to the "my_lib" directory.  So it looks like even through a "my_lib" directory is created, it is not made available as "my_lib" library for VHDL compile.

If using the Aldec Active-HDL Command Line Interface (CLI) through `vsimsa.bat` it works fine.

What is required to make Tcl `vlib` command work from the GUI Tcl console window?

It probably looks like the problem is that a local "library.cfg" file is not created just by doing `vlib my_lib`, so in this case, how to create a local "library.cfg" file for simple module compile and simulation?

Comment: Try any other name rather than `work`. Work is not a full separate library, it refers to "the current default library". So, `vlib work` is a bit like saying `mkdir .` in Linux. Work should simply ... work ... without extra steps.

Comment: The `vlib my_work` gives same result.  Also, I would expect that it is required to make the "work" library before it can be used as default compile destination library.

Comment: @BrianDrummond: Based on the answer from kraigher I see your point about the special "work" library, thus I have changed the example library name to "my_lib", since it makes no change for the question and problem.

Comment: Then all I can think of is that there is some kind of permissions problem on that directory. As Aldec only support Windows, I don't use it myself, so I can't help further.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the root cause of your problem but I just feel the need to enlighten you about the misuse of work as a library name.

`work` is really not a valid library name in VHDL. It is also not some kind of pre-defined default library. The VHDL standard defines `work` as a special alias for the current working library. Thus one can use `work` inside a VHDL file to reference other design units within the same library without knowing the name of the library into which they will be analyzed. Since `work` is a special alias it does not need to be referenced with a `library work` clause before any `use work.pkg.all` clauses.

Unfortunately many VHDL tools allow a designer create libraries named `work`, some even encourage it contributing to the confusion. This works fine as long as no design unit in another library tries to reference a design unit within the badly named work library. This is because the `work` name will be an alias for the other library within the context of files analyzed into that library.

This fact is little known even among experienced VHDL designers. Maybe the root cause of the confusion is that many tools often talk about a "work library" meaning the "current work library whatever it is called" which people interpreted literally to mean it should actually be named work.

### Example of work problem:

#### pkg.vhd

```
package pkg is
end package;
```

#### file.vhd

```
use work.pkg.all;
```

#### Good case

```
vcom -work lib pkg.vhd
vcom -work lib file.vhd
```

The files pkg.vhd and file.vhd can be compiled into a library with *any* name since they use the `work` alias.

#### Bad case

```
vcom -work work pkg.vhd
vcom -work lib file.vhd
```

There will be an error on the second command since `work` refers to `lib` when analyzing file.vhd since the current working library was `lib`. 
It is impossible to reference anything in the badly named `work` library from within `lib` since all references containing the special alias `work` will be translated into `lib`.

Comment: Thanks you for the great explanation, but since it does not answer the question as you note, I will not mark it as accepted.  I really don't get why somebody down voted it; it does not answer the question, but it is a great and relevant contribution, and I believe as you note, that it may be little known even among experienced VHDL designers.

Answer (score 0):

It is appears like it is not possible to create a library outside a workspace with design, so this has to be created.

See also the question and answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30936868/3989931